# How to automatically transfer all ebooks from iphone to iPad

Tags: data-synchronization, books

I am using my iPhone to download and or purchase ebooks (sometimes pdf sometimes ePub). Those are not all purchased from apple.

I would like to know how to transfer them automatically From my iPhone to my iPad.
What happens now is that I see the title but I have to download it manually.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Are you using the Apple Books app? Are you logged into both the devices with the same Apple ID? Do you use iCloud?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379976/if-add-a-file-to-books-do-i-need-to-keep-the-original-file/379977#379977